# Fade in from a background to another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say my element has background-image:background1.png.

How can I make the element's background fadein into background2.png without fading the first one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just position a second element (with background2.png) right on top of the first.  And fade in the second element.

Comment: So using z-index? This means I would have to do 10 different indexes for what I need to create. Or do I just create all divs on top and set what all of them except the current one to hidden. And then when i need to fadein, i fade in the one i need and then set the previous one to hidden?

Comment: Kon has the correct idea here, but you can automate it easily with CSS and JQuery - see my example.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can automate it with JQuery:

```
  $('.oldclass').prepend('<div class="newclass"></div>');
  $('.newclass').fadeIn('slow');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/GKUnF/

Comment: Seriously why the downvote, lol this code does exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice url where how to do that is explained clearly :

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations

But it require to create an image containing both, using CSS Sprites to achieve this...

Answer (score -1):

Really, there isn't an easy or elegant way to do this. CSS animations rely on the fact that things like opacity have in-between values (i.e. they are continuous).

The best solution might be to have to separate divs with their respective backgrounds, positioning them right on top of each other. Then hide the second by default, and call `fadeIn('slow')` when you want to change to its background.